# Link error building Qt 5.5 source code

Tags: qt

I'm having problems building Qt 5.5 from the Git Source.
Does anyone know what is causing this and how to solve it?

I've been following these steps.
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-building.html

```
qplacemanagerengineosm.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual struct QMetaObject const * __thiscall QPlaceDetailsR
eplyUnsupported::metaObject(void)const " (?metaObject@QPlaceDetailsReplyUnsupported@@UBEPBUQMetaObject@@XZ)
qplacemanagerengineosm.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void * __thiscall QPlaceDetailsReplyUnsupported::qt_
metacast(char const *)" (?qt_metacast@QPlaceDetailsReplyUnsupported@@UAEPAXPBD@Z)
qplacemanagerengineosm.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual int __thiscall QPlaceDetailsReplyUnsupported::qt_met
acall(enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)" (?qt_metacall@QPlaceDetailsReplyUnsupported@@UAEHW4Call@QMetaObject@@HPAPAX@Z)
qplacemanagerengineosm.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual struct QMetaObject const * __thiscall QPlaceContentR
eplyUnsupported::metaObject(void)const " (?metaObject@QPlaceContentReplyUnsupported@@UBEPBUQMetaObject@@XZ)
qplacemanagerengineosm.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void * __thiscall QPlaceContentReplyUnsupported::qt_
metacast(char const *)" (?qt_metacast@QPlaceContentReplyUnsupported@@UAEPAXPBD@Z)
qplacemanagerengineosm.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual int __thiscall QPlaceContentReplyUnsupported::qt_met
acall(enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)" (?qt_metacall@QPlaceContentReplyUnsupported@@UAEHW4Call@QMetaObject@@HPAPAX@Z)
qplacemanagerengineosm.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual struct QMetaObject const * __thiscall QPlaceSearchSu
ggestionReplyUnsupported::metaObject(void)const " (?metaObject@QPlaceSearchSuggestionReplyUnsupported@@UBEPBUQMetaObject@@XZ)
qplacemanagerengineosm.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void * __thiscall QPlaceSearchSuggestionReplyUnsuppo
rted::qt_metacast(char const *)" (?qt_metacast@QPlaceSearchSuggestionReplyUnsupported@@UAEPAXPBD@Z)
qplacemanagerengineosm.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual int __thiscall QPlaceSearchSuggestionReplyUnsupporte
d::qt_metacall(enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)" (?qt_metacall@QPlaceSearchSuggestionReplyUnsupported@@UAEHW4Call@QMetaObject@@HPAPAX@Z)

qplacemanagerengineosm.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual struct QMetaObject const * __thiscall QPlaceMatchRep
lyUnsupported::metaObject(void)const " (?metaObject@QPlaceMatchReplyUnsupported@@UBEPBUQMetaObject@@XZ)
qplacemanagerengineosm.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void * __thiscall QPlaceMatchReplyUnsupported::qt_me
tacast(char const *)" (?qt_metacast@QPlaceMatchReplyUnsupported@@UAEPAXPBD@Z)
qplacemanagerengineosm.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual int __thiscall QPlaceMatchReplyUnsupported::qt_metac
all(enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)" (?qt_metacall@QPlaceMatchReplyUnsupported@@UAEHW4Call@QMetaObject@@HPAPAX@Z)
F:\Code\qt5\qtbase\plugins\geoservices\qtgeoservices_osm.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 12 unresolved externals
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\BIN\link.EXE"' : return code '0x460'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\BIN\nmake.EXE"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cd' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cd' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cd' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cd' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cd' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
```

Comment: Where did you put Qt archive?

Comment: Allt the code from Git is located here:   F:\Code\qt5

Comment: and at which step does it bug ?

Comment: I run "configure -developer-build -opensource -nomake tests" in the terminal with Success. Then run "nmake" in the DOS prompt it builds for quite a while and then I get the Link Error

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. Maybe check qt bug reports.

Comment: This is Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: Yes it's building using Visual Studio 2013. I couldn't find anything on the QT bug reports

Comment: Try to configure with `-platform win32-msvc2013`

Comment: Do I need to do some clean up before I run nmake again ?

Comment: `nmake confclean` -> `configure <options>` -> `nmake clean` -> `nmake`

Comment: NMAKE : fatal error U1073: don't know how to make 'confclean'

Comment: Well, clean the repository then. `git clean -xdf`